# Git Lfs. Почему пушится не весь проект?

Tags: git, gitlab, unreal-engine-4

Имею проект на UnrealEngine. Хочу запушить проект на GitLab. Использую встроенный source control в Unreal. Проект весит 700мб. Но при пуше на gitlab вижу лишь 5.4мб данных[image: Скрин с gitlab]

Пытался пушить и через консоль, и через GitHub Desktop. Результат один и тот же,
подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема может быть в файле .gitignore (файл, куда прописуются файлы/папки, которые git будет "игнорировать" при выгрузке в репозиторий

Comment: к сожалению не в нём дело, проверял его:(

Comment: Таки что именно не пушится?

Comment: А вы, кстати, знаете как lfs работает?

Comment: как работает lfs я не знаю. пушится то вроде и всё(на gitlab лежат все файлы и папки которые я пушил), но при pull мои текстуры, материалы и остальное, что я так понимаю находится под контролем lfs, не открываются.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/lfs/manage_large_binaries_with_git_lfs.html

Answer (score 0):

В папке с проектом есть файл .gitignore (скорее всего скрыт), в нем содержится список всех папок и файлов которые игнорируются при загрузки на репозиторий. Подробнее узнать о gitignore можно в этой [статье](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/git_base/lessons/git_gitignore/theory_unit).